# How to access custom variable inside mailgun template?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mailgun, html-templates

I use mailgun with nodejs and want to use one of their custom templates.

```
// using template
var resetlink = 'https://myurl.com/reset/dkadlkw334sada';
var dataMail = {
  from: 'Me <me@me.com>',
  to: 'mail@gmail.com',
  subject: 'password reset',
    template: "pwrecovery",
  "v:link":resetlink
};

// execute send
mg.messages().send(dataMail, function(error, body) {
  if (error) {
 
  }
  console.log(body);
});
```

This works fine and I can see the mail delivered with this variable in the log console of mailgun.

However, I need this link inside the email template.
I tried

```
<td class="em_white" height="42" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold; height:42px;"><a href=%recipient.link% target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; line-height:42px; display:block;">RESET YOUR PASSWORD</a></td>
```

and as well:

```
<p> the link: {{recipient-variables.link}} </p>
```

But none of that worked. How can I access and show this variable, the resetlink, inside the html template?

Comment: Did you solve this? I can't render a link too. "https://google.com" renders fine, but if I send "sth://" it's blank.

Comment: For anyone arriving here and wondering what the syntax is. Add {{{ link }}} and make sure the variable is an <a href='http..' /a> tag with the actual https destination in it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mailgun uses Handlebars templates by default, you could use the "triple-stash" syntax {{{link}}} instead of {{link}} to prevent Handlebars from escaping the HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Add `{{{ link }}}` to the mailgun template and make sure the variable that is assigned link is like this

```
<a href='http//google.com' /a>
```

A tag with the actual https link in it and passed as template variable.

```
  const templateVars = {
         link: `<a href="${link}">Link</a>`}
```